Showing that a certain current in Rubakov transforms in the adjoint representation
I've been working through exercises in Rubakov's "Classical Theory of Gauge Fields" and am stuck on one of the exercises. Rubakov has defined a current with components
$$j_\mu^a = -i [\phi^\dagger T^a D_\mu \phi - (D_\mu \phi)^\dagger T^a \phi],$$
where $\phi$ is a scalar field transforming under the fundamental representation of $SU(n)$ and $T^a$ is a representation of a generators of the $SU(n)$ Lie algebra.
My understanding is that $j_\mu = j_\mu^a T^a$ transforming under the adjoint representation means that it would transform as (for $\omega \in SU(n)$):
$$j_\mu \mapsto j_\mu' =  -i [\phi^\dagger T^a D_\mu \phi - (D_\mu \phi)^\dagger T^a \phi] \omega T^a \omega^\dagger \tag 1$$
However, when I try to do the calculation (given that $\phi \mapsto \omega \phi$, $\phi^\dagger \mapsto \phi^\dagger \omega^\dagger$, and $D_\mu \phi$ transforms the same way):
$$ j_\mu'= -i [\phi^\dagger \omega^\dagger T^a \omega D_\mu \phi - (D_\mu \phi)^\dagger \omega^\dagger T^a \omega \phi] T^a,$$
and it's not obvious to me that this is equal to (1). I've tried substituting $k^a = \omega^\dagger T^a \omega$ to get a different set of orthonormal generators for the Lie algebra, giving us:
$$j_\mu'= -i [\phi^\dagger k^a D_\mu \phi - (D_\nu \phi)^\dagger k^a \phi]  \omega k^a \omega^\dagger = \omega \left\{-i [\phi^\dagger k^a D_\mu \phi - (D_\mu \phi)^\dagger k^a \phi] k^a \right\} \omega^\dagger,$$
which would be what we want if $$-i [\phi^\dagger k^a D_\mu \phi - (D_\nu \phi)^\dagger k^a \phi] k^a = -i [\phi^\dagger T^a D_\mu \phi - (D_\nu \phi)^\dagger T_a \phi] T^a,$$
but it's not obvious to me why this would be true, and I actually suspect that it's not.
My suspicion is that there's something that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding here. Where am I going wrong in this calculation?

Many QFT courses start with two weeks of remedial group theory based on SU(2). So I will illustrate your point with SU(2), where the generators $T^a$ in the fundamental are the three Pauli matrices halved, with the obvious Lie Algebra. To infinitesimal order, then,
$$\omega= \exp(i \theta^a \tau^a/2) = {\mathbb 1} + i\theta^a \tau^a/2 +O(\theta^2).
$$
The current defined then, is in the Lie algebra, and transforms as a real isovector!
$$j_\mu^a \mapsto j_\mu'^a =  -i (\phi^\dagger \omega^\dagger T^a \omega D_\mu \phi - (D_\mu \phi)^\dagger \omega^\dagger T^a \omega \phi) = j_\mu^a + \epsilon ^{abc}j_\mu^b\theta^c+ O(\theta^2).
$$
But this is exactly the adjoint transformation law of the three generators,
$$\tau^a/2 \mapsto \tau '^a /2=   \tau^a/2 + \epsilon ^{abc} \tau^b\theta^c/2+ O(\theta^2),
$$ an orthogonal isorotation,
by the very exact same calculation.
Check that $ j_\mu^a \tau^a/2$ is a singlet, lacking free adjoint indices, so the primed transform is identical, $ j_\mu^a \tau^a/2=j_\mu ' ^{a} \tau '^{a}/2 $. A scalar dot product of two isovectors.
You may extend the argument to all orders in θ, (recall exponentials of Pauli matrices are computable exactly!); and to all groups involved in R's construction.
